# Selecting rows from one table not in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
table_a_mod (2 million rows)
table_a (2 million rows + new live data)
```

`table_a_mod` is identical to table `table_a` except for two extra columns

`table_a` is a "live" table with data being written to it semi-regularly.

To keep `table_a_mod` up to date I would like to copy data from `table_a` to `table_a_mod`

By using a regular join, I am able to select the data:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a t1
LEFT JOIN table_a_mod t2
USING(id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

However, this query takes about 1 minute to run.

Is there a more efficient query along the lines of:

```
SELECT  *
FROM table_a t1
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT id 
  FROM table_a_mod
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1
) t2
USING (id)
WHERE t1.id > t2.id
```

ie. Get the largest id from table t2. Select all rows from table t1 with id greater than that number.

I've tried different permutations of the above query but I'm falling short.

**Edit 1**

In response to @danblack

EXPLAIN {slow_query}

```
"1" "SIMPLE"    "table_a"   "ALL"   \N  \N  \N  \N  "2353123"   ""
"1" "SIMPLE"    "table_a_mod"   "eq_ref"    "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "db.table_a.id" "1" "Using where; Not exists"
```

> I'm assuming id is a primary key in both

Yes. id is a primary key in both.

> Are the tables innodb and is there sufficient innodb_buffer_pool_size to hold both tables?

Both tables are innodb. And innodb_buffer_pool_size is 8388608

> Is "new live data" always of an id above the previous table?

Yes, because it's auto incrementing

> Why are you keeping two nearly identical tables

It is a temporary situation. We will drop the older one and use the newer one.

Comment: There is limits how efficient comparing 2 million rows from two tables can be. If you change `SELECT *` to `SELECT t1.id, t2.id` is that quicker? What does `EXPLAIN {query}` show? I'm assuming id is a primary key in both? Are the tables innodb and is there sufficient innodb_buffer_pool_size to hold both tables?  Is "new live data" always of an id above the previous table? Why are you keeping two nearly identical tables, perhaps the performance and be improved by answering that.

Comment: @danblack Thanks for your comment. I've added the clarifications in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much RAM do you have?  If you have more than 4GB, set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 70% of available RAM.  This is the most important thing to tune.  With it set to only 8M, you are definitely I/O-bound.  Increasing the size will probably shrink the time to under 10 seconds.

Your second idea should be good (assuming the only new rows have higher ids), but let's get rid of the `LEFT` and use `MAX`:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  table_a t1
    JOIN  
        ( SELECT  MAX(id) AS max_id
            FROM  table_a_mod ) t2
    WHERE  t1.id > t2.max_id
```

Comment: Thank you both (@Rick James and @Akina). I've tweaked it a little and it works perfectly.

    SELECT  *
    FROM  table_a t1
    JOIN  
        ( SELECT  MAX(id) AS id
            FROM  table_a_mod
        ) t2
    WHERE  t1.id > t2.id

Comment: In the interest of accuracy, I will mark it as correct once the SQL has been edited correctly.

Comment: "

How much RAM do you have? If you have more than 4GB, set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 70% of available RAM. This is the most important thing to tune. " @denormalizer Assuming the physical server is dedicated to run MySQL only..

Comment: @Akina - Thanks.  I changed it in a different way.  (An example of "overloading" a name can cause trouble.)

Comment: @Akina - Rats, I did not simplify it enough!